# Use blade inside a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I woke up this morning with a stupid question. Can you put blade inside a JavaScript variable:

```
 var NoImg = '{{ asset('img/ni-img.png') }}';
```

that will output as a string, all I need is it to output an image

Comment: Yes. Blade is a server side template engine. If your have a blade view file, her will be executed before the javascript. In your case, NoImg will have the expanded value returned by the helper asset() when the html is returned from the server.

Comment: You entirely can - in fact I've used this more times than I care to admit in Laravel.

Comment: @Tor did you do it the same way i did?

Comment: @Yosef Yep - that will directly inject the path to your image into your JS string's single-quotes. If you needed to then use that string as an image, you'd need to set an `img` `.src` to the path.

Comment: putting an image in a javascript variable is a bit unclear. Do you mean a url? or what.

Comment: @Tor thanks bro that worked post that as a answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - that will directly inject the path to your image into your JS string's single-quotes.

If you needed to then use that string as an image, you'd need to set an `img` `.src` to the path, like

```
document.getElementByID('myImage').src = '{{ asset('img/ni-img.png') }}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's best to use `json_encode` to make sure the resulting output is JavaScript-friendly:

```
var NoImg = {!! json_encode(asset('img/ni-img.png')) !!};
```

PHP will add the quotation marks (for strings), any necessary escaping characters (if you have a `'` in your filename, for example), and will handle more complex data structures like arrays/objects too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Blade is a server side template engine. If your have a blade view file, her will be executed before the javascript. In your case, NoImg will have the expanded value returned by the helper asset() when the html is returned from the server.

This will be work fine:

```
<?php
    // variable from your controller...
    $image = 'https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
?>

// your js inside of a blade file...
var image = new Image(272, 92);
image.src = '{{ $image }}'; // or asset("path/to/your/image.png")
document.body.appendChild(image);
```